# How to pass model name in Angular Typescript

Tags: angular

I have multiple checkboxes in my .html, each checkbox has its own [(ngModel)] name. Is it possible to pass the [(ngModel)] name? something like:

```
<input id="chkEndUserOfficeV" name="chkEndUserOfficeV" type="checkbox" 
[(ngModel)]="Role.EndUserOffice.View" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCheckBox(modelName)">

<input id="chkEndUserOfficeC" name="chkEndUserOfficeC" type="checkbox" 
[(ngModel)]="Role.EndUserOffice.Create" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCheckBox(modelName)">
```

Is there a way to do it instead of this:

```
<input id="chkEndUserOfficeV" name="chkEndUserOfficeV" type="checkbox" 
[(ngModel)]="Role.EndUserOffice.View" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCheckBox('Role.EndUserOffice.View')">

<input id="chkEndUserOfficeC" name="chkEndUserOfficeC" type="checkbox" 
[(ngModel)]="Role.EndUserOffice.Create" (ngModelChange)="onSelectCheckBox('Role.EndUserOffice.Create')">
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at the [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

Comment: Is Role an enum or an object?